# Спор насчёт стилистики

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста,  выражение "Отовариваться кредитной картой в магазине"  является разговорным и не годиться для рекламного текста?   Мне сделали такое замечание, более того, сказали, что слово "отовариваться" устаревшее, это неуместный архаизм, сродни слову "авоська". 
Та же проблема возникла со словом "подспорье".  Выражение "Кредитная карта послужит вам хорошим подспорьем" неуместно для рекламы. 
Неужели правда?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Слово **отовариваться** - жаргонизм, заменяющий выражение "обзаводиться товаром" (как правило, не платя за него деньгами). Чаще всего это слово означало получение товара в обмен на *оплаченные* какой-либо организацией *талоны* (или иные документы), предназначенные, например, для расчётов за питание спортсменов или командированных. Такие талоны доставались бесплатно и могли быть использованы как по прямому назначению, так и для обмена на продукты длительного хранения. Более "формальным" в этом аспекте (даже ведомственным, фигурировавшим в распоряжениях) выражением было эквивалентное **отоварить талоны**. Поскольку такие ситуации стали относительно редки, слово можно назвать и *устаревшим* , но главное, в случае с кредитной картой употреблено оно **не по назначению** (хотя в современном употреблении его и можно услышать как просторечие, связываемое с "товаром" произвольным образом, - кто как понимает это слово): в этом случае имеет место обычная *оплата стоимости* товара *деньгами*.

**Подспорье** - обычно так называли источник дополнительного дохода или продовольствия у бедных (свой огород, который помогает прокормиться, и т. п.). Так что вам правду сказали.

Answer (score 1):

ОТОВАРИТЬСЯ - получить товар.

"Отовариваться чем-то" — неверное употребление слова *отовариваться*.

ПОДСПОРЬЕ, -я; ср. Поддержка, помощь в чём-л. (в каком-л. деле, занятии и т.п.); то, что является помощью, поддержкой. Давать деньги в п. кому-л. Материальное, духовное п. Не иметь в жизни подспорья. Главным подспорьем семьи был огород. Мемуары участников событий - хорошее п. в работе над романом.

"Кредитная карта послужит подспорьем" — неверное употребление слова *подспорье*. Может создаться впечатление, что кредитная карта — это доступ к дополнительным деньгам.

Answer (score 0):

ОТОВАРИТЬСЯ, -рюсь, -ришься; св. 1. Получить товар (обычно в исполнение какого-л. обязательства). О. в гастрономе. **2. Разг. Приобрести для себя нужный товар. <Отовариваться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв. Отоваривание (см.).**

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Словари не отмечают у этого слова **устаревший оттенок, нет у этого слова и  помет. жарг.** 
Единственное, что вам правильно сказали, в рекламном тексте это слово неуместно!